# Apply like function on an array is SQL Server

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

I am getting array from front end to perform filters according that inside the SQL query.

I want to apply a `LIKE` filter on the array. How to add an array inside `LIKE` function?

I am using Angular with Html as front end and Node as back end.

Array being passed in from the front end:

```
 [ "Sports", "Life", "Relationship", ...]
```

SQL query is :

```
SELECT *
FROM Skills
WHERE Description LIKE ('%Sports%')

SELECT *
FROM Skills
WHERE Description LIKE ('%Life%')

SELECT *
FROM Skills
WHERE Description LIKE ('%Relationship%')
```

But I am getting an array from the front end - how to create a query for this?

Comment: Pass in a table valued parameter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017 Then this becomes trivial.

Comment: What _programming language_ are you using on the backend. I am sure you're using one.

Comment: @SalmanA I am Using Node JS as backend.

Comment: You can parse the JSON in Node and generate a query that uses table valued pairs. If you're using SQL 2016+ there is an easier option too.

Comment: Also please realize that since you are using leading wildcards you have rendered your query nonSARGable and any indexes are fruitless on the Description column.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2017 you can use [`OPENJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to consume the JSON string as-is:

```
SELECT *
FROM skills
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM OPENJSON('["Sports", "Life", "Relationship"]', '$') AS j
    WHERE skills.description LIKE '%' + j.value + '%'
)
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c9c3b655d3eee0107291b117ad169bfc)

Comment: I am also doing like this. But problem is that array coming from front end is  ["Sports","Life"] and the error from sql is 'JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character ''' is found at position 1. '''

Comment: You're obviously passing invalid json. Perhaps you have extra quotes around.

Comment: It is impossible to tell. But perhaps if you're using parameters you would do `... FROM OPENJSON(@p1, '$') AS ...` and value of `@p1` would be `JSON.stringify(that_array)`

Answer (score 0):

As an example, for SQL Server 2016+ and `STRING_SPLIT()`:

```
DECLARE @Str NVARCHAR(100) = N'mast;mode'

SELECT name FROM sys.databases sd
INNER JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@Str, N';') val ON sd.name LIKE N'%' + val.value + N'%'

-- returns:

name
------
master
model
```

Worth to mention that input data to be strictly controlled, since such way can lead to SQL Injection attack

As the alternative and more safer and simpler approach: SQL can be generated on an app side this way:

```
 Select * from Skills 
 WHERE (
     Description Like '%Sports%' 
 OR  Description Like '%Life%' 
 OR  Description Like '%Life%' 
     )
```

Comment: STRING_SPLIT is invalid object in my case. I am using SQL Server 2017

Comment: @AmandeepSingh, the compatibility level of a database set to SQL 2014 or lower, it should be set to at least SQL2016

Comment: can we use STRING_SPLIT without Joins?

Comment: @AmandeepSingh, Not with `LIKE` statement. Please note, that I have added an alternative approach, that does not use any joins, perhaps it can be a better alternative for your case

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using a join? You could do it without joins but it becomes far more ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `map()`-call on the `words` array will allow you to generate the corresponding queries, which you can then execute (with or without joining them first into a single string).

Demo:

```js
var words = ["Sports", "Life", "Relationship"];
var template = "Select * From Skills Where Description Like ('%{0}%')";

var queries = words.map(word => template.replace('{0}', word));
var combinedQuery = queries.join("\r\n");

console.log(queries);
console.log(combinedQuery);
```

Comment: You need to add multiple words using `or` i.e. the query would look like `WHERE col like '%life%' or col like '%sports%'` etc

Comment: That is your assumption, OP does not mention this at all.